# UIWebView resize slow

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

Resizing my UIWebView(s) is slow. When resizing multiple UIWebViews (with large content) it can take seconds on an iPad2. This is the code I use:

```
tmpUIWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
```

I know resizing can be done quickly because:
- The Dolphin HD browser on iPad resizes multiple tabs to fullscreen very quickly.
- Also when I scroll the UIWebView while resizing, the resizing is done quickly.

How can I resize the UIWebViews quickly (just like in Dolphin HD browser)? Is there some kind of trick?

Thanks for helping!

Gerben

Comment: Could you provide more information on the context of the call? It seems like there is something else going on as to why the resizing is slow.. A little more code or something more visual would help.

Comment: @notreallyJake Thanks for helping. I've changed the code. This is all I'm doing. Offcourse a webpage is loaded in the UIWebView

Answer (score 1):

This is how I hide a view slowly

```
- (void)hideLoadinNotification{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];
infoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)showLoadinNotification{
[infoView setNeedsLayout];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];
infoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context{
if ([animationID isEqual:@"fadeOut"]) {
    [infoView removeFromSuperview];
}    
if ([animationID isEqual:@"fadeIn"]) {
    [self.tableView addSubview:infoView];
}    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transform property, but the content will be resized too.